# How to force Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I want to create my own `jackson` `ObjectMapper` bean, as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@AutoConfigureBefore(JacksonAutoConfiguration.class) //even this does not help
public class MyConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        return builder.createXmlMapper(true).build(); //much more configurations
    }
}
```

Problem: the bean is never created, but instead the default `JacksonAutoConfiguration` is executed:

```
package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson;

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(ObjectMapper.class)
public class JacksonAutoConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ObjectMapper.class)
        public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            return builder.createXmlMapper(false).build(); //this is always executed!
        }
}
```

So somehow the `ObjectMapper` bean is not present yet when `JacksonAutoConfiguration` is evaluated. But why?

By debugging with breakpoints I can also see that my bean is **never** invoked!
BUT what I noticed: even though I have the `@AutoConfigureBefore`, the jackson autoconfig is still run *before* any of the beans in `MyConfig`. Strange?

Comment: Just to clarify: you placed debugger breakpoint there and it is never invoked, right?

Comment: Exactly, my `ObjectMapper` bean is completely neglected (which is not the case for all the other beans in the same `MyConfig` class.

Comment: Can you provide more context for your question? From what you've shown it's not clear that `MyConfig` should be used. Are you running your application as a jar, a war, in your IDE, something else? What does its main method look like if it has one? A [minimal, complete, verifiable, example](/help/mcve) would make things much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) Spring's documentation for customised `ObjectMapper`, this is what it says:

> If you want to replace the default ObjectMapper completely, either
>   define a `@Bean` of that type and mark it as `@Primary`, or, if you prefer
>   the builder-based approach, define a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
>   `@Bean`. Note that in either case this will disable all
>   auto-configuration of the ObjectMapper.

If defining `ObjectMapper` bean does not help, could you try defining `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean instead?

Also, could you try defining the beans into a class annotated with `@Configuration`?

Comment: It turned out I had to move the bean definition to it's own `@Configuration` class. I don't know why it is skipped if in main `SpringBootApplication` class?

Comment: maybe `@SpringBootApplication` does not extend `@Configuration` annotation/interface? Anyway, you can mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you.